# TypeScript: custom error class, object array interface

Tags: typescript

basically i'm trying to make a custom error, to display the following structure:

```
message: ''
statusCode: ''
type: ''
errors: [
    {
      "field": "name",
      "code": "missing_field"
    }
    {
      "resource": "Issue",
      "field": "email",
      "code": "missing_field"
    }
]
```

In other words, I need to create an array in my function, to store the field errors and send to my error, if it is more than an input, an array or just an object of:

```
export interface errors_fields {
  field: string;
  code: string;
}
```

**My Custom Error Class:**

```
export interface errors_fields {
  field: string;
  code: string;
}

export class UnprocessableEntity extends Error {
  message: string;
  statusCode = 422;
  errors: [errors_fields] | errors_fields | null;
  type: 'UnprocessableEntity';
  public response;
  constructor(message: string, errors: [errors_fields] | errors_fields | null) {
    super(message);
    this.response = { message: message, errors: errors, statusCode: this.statusCode, type: 'UnprocessableEntity' };
  }
}
```

**My async func**

```
type InputErrors = {
  field: string;
  code: string;
};
  async findOrCreate(data: Partial<User>): createUser {
    let validationErrors: InputErrors | [InputErrors];
    let user = await this.userRep.findOne({ where: { email: data.email } });
    //email length
    if (!(data.email.length > 1 && data.email.length < 250)) {
      validationErrors.push({ field: 'email', code: 'invalid_field' });
    }
    console.log(validationErrors);
    // if (user) throw new Error(errorName.UNAUTHORIZED);
    data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 12);
    user = await this.userRep.save({
      ...data,
    });
    return user;
  }
```

but i got error here:

```
  if (!(data.email.length > 1 && data.email.length < 250)) {
      validationErrors.push({ field: 'email', code: 'invalid_field' });
    }
```

with this:

> Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'. 27
>   validationErrors.push({ field: 'email', code: 'invalid_field' });

Comment: Could you modify this code so as to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask], suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?  It looks like you are not initializing `validationErrors`, and its type `InputErrors | [InputErrors]` is either an `InputErrors` or an array containing exactly one element of type `InputErrors`.  Is that your intent?  Or are you trying to say `InputErrors[] | InputErrors`?  Without something I can demonstrate for myself in an IDE it's hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: Hello i had done it in a graphql project, i will make a reproducible example, basically i need to return an array of objects with the errors

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-paper-qhs20?file=/index.ts i try this

Comment: basically i need to save the errors in an array with the following structure:
code,
field

Comment: `validationErrors` should be defined as `InputErrors[]` and it looks it is not initialized at all...